# system call poll for /tmp/.X11-unix/X1 takes too long

Tags: system-calls, x11vnc

I have a GUI program that takes too long to respond, so I used `strace -T` to report all its system calls.
I find the reason causing the program slow is `poll` costs too much time. For example, the results of `strace -T` contain something like this:

```
poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=9, revents=POLLIN}]) <5.031644>
......
poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=9, revents=POLLIN}]) <7.840762>
```

It says the 2 `poll` system calls cost 5.03 and 7.84 seconds to finish.
By searching for `fd=9` in the report, I find it corresponds to socket `/tmp/.X11-unix/X1`, as the following contents indicate:

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 9 <0.000008>
connect(9, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X1"}, 20) = 0 <0.000008>
```

I guess the long `poll` is caused by high-latency response of `X11`. So I opened a new desktop via `VNC` on the same machine and ran the same program on it, everything is OK.

But I cannot find a way to run the program normally on my native desktop, can anyone give me some suggestions on how to do it?